# grid-template-column size cut in half when shown in dev tools

Tags: html, css, css-grid

Im trying to make a simple 3x2 grid

Here is my code

```
.grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 100px 100px 100px;
    grid-template-columns: 100px 100px;
    border: 3px solid lightgrey;}
```

when I inspect the track size of the grid in dev tools my 3 rows at 100px but both my colums at at 50px.

I've tried checking for css overrides, ive checked computed values and the value for the columns were 100px 100px, and tried box-sizing but nothing seems to work

Comment: It's better if you post your HTML too, in a way that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.